# How can I write a query to aggregate multiple strings into one field?

Tags: mysql, aggregate, string

I am trying to merge three tables.
The first table has id and data_name, 
second table data_id, option_id and property,
third table user_id, data_id.

For example:

```
first table
+----+-----------+
| id | data_name |
+----+-----------+
| 1  + veri1     |
| 2  + veri2     |
| 3  + veri3     |
+---++-----------+

second table 
+----------+----------+-----------+
data_id    | property | option_id |
+----------+----------+-----------+
| 1        | blue     | 1         |
| 1        | cold     | 2         |
| 2        | gray     | 1         |
| 2        | hot      | 2         |
| 3        | green    | 1         |
| 3        | cold     | 1         |
+----------+----------+-----------+

third table
+----------+-----------+
| user_id  | data_id   |
+----------+-----------+
| 1        | 2         |
| 2        | 3         |
| 3        | 1         |
+----------+-----------+
```

I want to get:

```
user: 1
data: veri2
properties: gray - hot
```

How do I write the SQL for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First start with the FROM clause. Where is the data stored that you want?

```
FROM user_first_table
JOIN property_second_table
JOIN user_data_third_table
```

Then consider the conditions you should join with (I find it easier to re-order the tables)

```
FROM user_data_third_table t 
JOIN user_first_table f ON f.id = t.user_id
JOIN property_second_table s ON s.data_id = t.data_id
```

Then narrow down with a WHERE clause, e.g. only want data for veri1

```
FROM user_data_third_table t 
JOIN user_first_table f ON f.id = t.user_id
JOIN property_second_table s ON s.data_id = t.data_id
WHERE f.data_name = 'veri1'
```

Then label the fields of data you want

```
SELECT f.id as 'user', f.data_name as 'data', s.property as 'properties'
FROM user_data_third_table t 
JOIN user_first_table f ON f.id = t.user_id
JOIN property_second_table s ON s.data_id = t.data_id
WHERE f.data_name = 'veri1'
```

Comment: It's probably `ON f.id = t.data_id`

Answer (score 1):

This query should do it. But your `property` will be comma separated instead of `-`.

```
Select user_id,data_name, GROUP_CONCAT(property)
From Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id = Table2.data_id
INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table1.id = Table3.data_id
GROUP BY Table1.id
```

Comment: "," can be replaced with "-" with the replace function: `replace(GROUP_CONCAT(property), ',', '-')`

Comment: @Lennart even better, [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) has `SEPARATOR`.